# Which device makes the HTTP request when an HttpClient inside an IActionResult calls an external server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, client-server

I am trying to understand some very basic stuff on ASP.NET MVC to get a clear hold on who does what but I lamentably fail so far.

Consider the following physical devices, one pc and 2 servers:

1. My physical Server where I host my ASP.NET website
2. An External Server, say the WorldBank
3. A user's PC connected to my website (i.e. My Server)

When the user visits my homepage, I want to display to him some data taken from the WorldBank (retrieve JSON from the WorldBank and displayed on my website as html).

I have this IAction in mind, say on the Index View:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://api.worldbank.org/countries?format=json");
       //Process data, perhaps put in a viewmodel and return View
    ...      
    }
    ...
  return View(model);
}
```

**Question**

Once my website is setup and running, if the user visits my Index page, which physical device makes the request to the WorldBank?
Is it the user's pc or is it My Server and how can I check this?

In my MVC learning curve I so far assumed that My Server runs what is inside the HomeController, and thus it is My Server which will make the call to the WorldBank.

Thanks for any clarification, and my apologies if this question is trivial.

Comment: You are correct in thinking it is the server. Since this is server-side programming this all happens on the server machine. your computer requests the route of Index, which is invoked by the server. The server executes the method that the index route points to and then returns the result  to your view which your browser then renders

Comment: Thanks very much Oliver for your answer. Do you have a hint on what I should look for in the dev tools of the browser (for instance), to check that it is My Server which is doing the call to the WorldBank? If I understand well, if I want the user to download the data, I would use AjAX in JS.

Comment: Hi, I'm not too sure on how you mean check? If you're using that code then it is executing on the server. What kind of format are you wanting users to download the data in?

Comment: I was wondering how, on a client browser for instance (or fiddle?) I could check that it is My Server which retrieves the data from the worldbank and not the browser. Said differently, I am looking for a way to check what you say so that I can see the dynamics and get a clear picture. I am using JSON data. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking some colleagues it seems that Oliver is right: What is inside a controller runs on the server.